# When is a Java local variable eligible for GC?

Tags: java

Given the following program:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class GCTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        List cache = new ArrayList();
        while (true) {
            cache.add(new GCTest().run());
            System.out.println("done");
        }
    }

    private byte[] run() throws IOException {
        Test test = new Test();
        InputStream is = test.getInputStream();
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte[] buff = new byte[256];
        int len = 0;
        while (-1 != (len = is.read())) {
            baos.write(buff, 0, len);
        }
        return baos.toByteArray();
    }

    private class Test {
        private InputStream is;

        public InputStream getInputStream() throws FileNotFoundException {
            is = new FileInputStream("GCTest.class");
            return is;
        }

        protected void finalize() throws IOException {
            System.out.println("finalize");
            is.close();
            is = null;
        }
    }
}
```

would you expect the finalize to ever be called when the while loop in the run method is still executing and the local variable test is still in scope?

More importantly, is this behaviour defined anywhere? Is there anything by Sun that states that it is implementation-defined?

This is kind of the reverse of the way this question has been asked before on SO where people are mainly concerned with memory leaks. Here we have the GC aggressively GCing a variable we still have an interest in. You might expect that because test is still "in scope" that it would not be GC'd.

For the record, it appears that sometimes the test "works" (i.e. eventually hits an OOM) and sometimes it fails, depending on the JVM implementation.

Not defending the way this code is written BTW, it's just a question that came up at work.

Comment: Just some nitpicking: Strictly speaking "local variables" are never eligible for GC, since they can only hold references or primitive values and only objects are GCed. Objects referenced by local variables might become eligible for GC however.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

While the object won't be garbage collected if it is still in scope, the JIT compiler might take it out of scope if the variable isn't actually used any further in the code (hence the differing behavior you are seeing) even though when you read the source code the variable still seems to be "in scope."

I don't understand why you care if an object is garbage collected if you don't reference it anymore in code, but if you want to ensure objects stay in memory, the best way is to reference them directly in a field of a class, or even better in a static field. If a static field references the object, it won't get garbage collected.

Edit: [Here](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6721588) is the explicit documentation you are looking for.

> `>` I'm assuming an object cannot die *before* a local reference to it has gone out of scope.
>
> This can not be assumed.  Neither the
> Java spec nor the JVM spec guarantees
> this.
>
> Just because a variable is in scope,
> doesn't mean the object it points to
> is reachable.  Usually it is the case
> that an object pointed to by an
> in-scope variable is reachable, but
> yours is a case where it is not.  The
> compiler can determine at jit time
> which variables are dead and does not
> include such variables in the oop-map.
> Since the object pointed to by "nt"
> can [sic - should be cannot] be
> reached from any live variable, it is
> eligible for collection.

Comment: The reason why we care is because of the finalize method. That is causing the program to fail. Yes, there are easy ways to fix it but the person who raised this believes that the test instance should not be GC'd before the run method exits because it is still "in scope". This testcase is a reduced version of a larger and more complex app.

Comment: @Dave: that person is wrong. Plain and simple.  The JLS and JVM specs do not make any guarantees that an "invisible" reference will not be garbage collected.

Comment: Excellent link Yishai, thanks! I find that case to be even more surprising - i.e. even though it is passed as a parameter to another method it is still eligible for GC

Comment: Remember, the Hotspot VM is way smarter than everyone on StackOverflow put together.

Answer (score 8):

I recommend that you and your co-worker read the [The Truth About Garbage Collection](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/performance/1st_edition/html/JPAppGC.fm.html).

Right at the start, it says this:

> The specification for the Java
>   platform makes very few promises about
>   how garbage collection actually works. [elided]
>
> While it can seem confusing, the fact
>   that the garbage collection model is
>   not rigidly defined is actually
>   important and useful-a rigidly defined
>   garbage collection model might be
>   impossible to implement on all
>   platforms. Similarly, it might
>   preclude useful optimizations and hurt
>   the performance of the platform in the
>   long term.

In your example, the `test` variable becomes "invisible" (see A.3.3 of above) in the `while` loop.  At this point some JVMs will continue to view the variable as containing a "hard reference", and other JVMs will treat it as if the variable has been nulled.  Either behaviour is acceptable for a compliant JVM

Quoting from the JLS edition 3 (section 12.6.1 paragraph 2):

> A reachable object is any object that
>   can be accessed in any potential
>   continuing computation from any live
>   thread.

Notice that reachability is not defined in terms of scopes at all.  The quoted text continues as follows:

> Optimizing transformations of
>   a program can be designed that reduce
>   the number of objects that are
>   reachable to be less than those which
>   would naively be considered reachable.
>   *For example, a compiler or code
>   generator may choose to set a variable
>   or parameter that will no longer be
>   used to null to cause the storage for
>   such an object to be potentially
>   reclaimable sooner.*

(My emphasis added.)  This means that an object object may be garbage collected and finalization may occur earlier or later than you would expect.  It is also worth noting that some JVMs take more than one GC cycles before unreachable objects are finalized.

The bottom line is that a program that depends on finalization happening earlier or later is inherently non-portable, and to my mind buggy.

Comment: I think that quote may be slightly misleading as it still encourages us to think in terms of local variable slots in a stack frame whereas the JIT compiler may optimize away any such notion. The earlier quote is maybe more accurate. For instance another colleague suggested that putting "test = null;" after the while loop would prevent the GC because it is keeping the variable "in use" but actually it makes no difference (doesn't count as "computation")

Comment: I would suggest that you tell your colleague that trying to second guess what JIT compilers might do is a bad idea.  Also, you need to bear in mind that the JLS is not intended to be easy for normal folks to understand.  The primary requirement is precision, not readability.  To really understand what it is (and is not) saying, you need to read it carefully and pedantically.

Comment: Sure, but in order to write correct code, you need to be easily able to understand the rules. The link you quote mentions invisibility being a source of confusion to developers but then just adds to it by referring to the scope of a try/catch block. The reachable definition you quote is much more understandable IMO. (Of course if the developers weren't using finalisers the way they are none of this would be a problem!)

Comment: "Of course if the developers weren't using finalisers the way they are none of this would be a problem!".  That's what I was getting.  In fact, you / they shouldn't be using finalizers at all.  I've never come across a case where they are a good solution.

Answer (score 4):

Slightly off-topic, but finalize() should never be used to close() a file.  The language does **not** guarantee that finalize() will ever get called.  Always use a try ... finally construct to guarantee file closure, database cleanup, etc.

Answer (score 1):

What are you observing that you find strange? Each time you execute run(), you create a new instance of Test. Once run completes, that instance of test is out of scope and eligible for garbage collection. Of course "eligible for garbage collection" and "is garbage collected" are not the same thing. I'd expect that if you run this program, you'd see a bunch of finalize messages scroll by as invocations of run complete. As the only console output I see is these messages, I don't see how you would know which instance of Test is being finalized when you see each message. You might get more interesting results if you added a println at the beginning of each invocation of run, and maybe even added a counter to the Test object that gets incremented each time a new one is created, and which is output with the finalize message. Then you could see what was really happening. (Well, maybe you're running this with a debugger, but that could also obscure more.)

Comment: No, the instance of test is being GC'd _during_ the while loop and before run completes. Because it is no longer actively in use (even though "in scope" as normally understood).

Try it and see.

Comment: I don't doubt that the compiler could optimize sufficiently to figure that out. My point was: How do you know? I don't see anything in the output of that program that would tell you that.

Answer (score 0):

As `test` is only used once, it can be removed immediately after the call to it. Even if the each call to `read` used a call to `getInputStream` instead of using the local `is` variable, use of the object could be optimised away. `FIleInputStream` cannot be finalised prematurely due to its use of locking. Finalisers are difficult.

In any case, your finaliser is pointless. The underlying `FileInputStream` will close itself on finalisation anyway.

Comment: I know, but not my code and it's anyway just a simplified testcase from a larger app that depends on variables "in scope" not disappearing. What I'm most interested in is whether there is any documentation that defines the notion of scope and states when an implementation is free to GC. Because a lot of people believe that the above test should work because the variable only drops out of scope (and becomes eligible for GC) when the run method returns.

Comment: It's defined as part of the Java Memory Model (in JLS 3rd Ed and updates to JVM Spec 2nd Ed).

Answer (score 0):

In theory Test must not be in the scope since it is at the method level run() and the local variables should be garbage collected as you come out of the method.However you are storing the results in list, and i have read it somehere that lists are prone for storing weak references that are not garbage collected easily (depending on jvm implementation).

Comment: @Rajat: your theory is only plausible if a JVM could store a completely unrelated reference in list.  That would be so egregious a violation of the specs that I would discount the possibility for any production quality JVM.

Comment: You might be right Stephen, I think i need to read and research further on this.