# Does adding scope {} brackets to let variables go out of scope have the same effect as calling and ending a function or some sort of empty loop?

Tags: java, scope, stack, brackets

I wonder if it is possible to let variables go out of scope while only adding brackets around some piece of code and if it's any different from the other ways to let variables go out of scope:

0) adding brackets:

```
private void methodExample() {
    {
        int example = 5;
    }
    //variable "example" out of scope
}
```

1) function call:

```
private void methodExample() {        
    justMakeItAMethod();
    //variable "example" out of scope
}

private void justMakeItAMethod() {
        int example = 5;
}
```

2) loop that ends like:

```
private void methodExample() {
    do {
        int example = 5;
    } while (false);
    //variable "example" out of scope
}
```

Does the way the variables go out of scope with respect to the stack differ per example?

The reason I thought of this: *[disclaimer I know this is a case of premature optimization]I have a low level function in which I have many different small independent parts of code with slightly different functionality, not enough in my opinion to make it a different function which would require a function call overhead, but enough parts to rather have variables already go out of scope.*

Comment: Don't post oictures of text here. Waste of your time and our bandwidth. Post the text.

Comment: What *exact* error message do you get with that code? What IDE is it? My guess is that that's really just a warning that you're not using the variable. The *last* line is invalid, as the variable is indeed out of scope.

Comment: @EJP You did not get the point of the picture. It was to visually indicate that the variable indeed went out of scope.

Comment: @JonSkeet I will add that as a disclaimer. It's only about the last line in red indicating that it is indeed as expected going out of scope. But I wonder what happens under the hood when this happens and if it's any different from a function or look going out of scope.

Comment: @Joop Nobody can get the point of the picture. It is all black. Waste of your time and my money. Don't do it.

Comment: This is precisely why posting text and an explanation would be better than posting the image...

Comment: Ok agreed. I will change it and make it better.

Comment: In any case you don't need to convince us that the variable went out of scope. The JLS says so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The behavior might differ depends on whether you have an interpreted or JIT-compiled frame. In JIT-compiled frame the object can be marked as free after the last usage of the variable even if it's still in the scope. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1363097/4856258) for example. In interpreted frames it will still reside in the stack frame variable slot even after the scope ends. On the other hand compiler reuses variable slots which are freed as scope ends. This can lead to the interesting results for interpreted frames:

```
public class LVTest {
    @Override
    protected void finalize() {
        System.out.println("Finalized");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        {
            LVTest t = new LVTest();
        }
        System.out.println("GC!");
        System.gc();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        System.out.println("GC!");
        System.gc();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        System.out.println("GC!");
        System.gc();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        System.out.println("Assign new var!");
        int a = 5;
        System.out.println("GC!");
        System.gc();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        System.out.println("Finish");
    }
}
```

The output is like this:

```
GC!
GC!
GC!
Assign new var!
GC!
Finalized
Finish
```

So no matter how many times we collect garbage our out-of-scope object is not finalized. But after we assign a new variable which reuses the same variable slot, we can finally free the original variable. Were this method JIT-compiled, the `Finalized` message would appear earlier.

In any case "scope end" is compiled to nothing in the bytecode, so JVM does not know where you close your curly brace. If you think that your code will be executed in interpreted frame, it's probably more safe to assign `null` to the variable after usage than using block and hope that new variables will be created after it. Though if you have a part of method which executes for a long time and does not use previously created variable, then it would be much better to split your method to smaller parts. In JIT-compiled frame you should not optimize this at all: JIT-compiler is smart.

Comment: But is it really smart enough to know where an inner scope ends without any bytecode instruction to tell it?

Comment: It doesn't know where the scope ends, but it does know when variable will not be used anymore (regardless whether the block ends or not).

Answer (score 2):

Bytecode investigation shows rather interesting results. The local variable table (inside the stack frame) has slots for each local variable. So, in case of *variables in code blocks*, the slots are overwritten by the next variable. Which means once the execution of the block is done, the variable is no longer available.

Code :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    {
        int x ;
        x=5;
        System.out.println(x);
    }

    int y = 1;
    System.out.println(y);
    {
        int x ;
        x=5;
        System.out.println(x);
    }
    int z = 2;
    System.out.println(z);

}


  LocalVariableTable:
    Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
        0      37     0  args   [Ljava/lang/String;
        2       7     1     x   I // in block
       11      26     1     y   I  
       20       7     2     x   I // in block
       29       8     2     z   I
```

So, there is *some* information being sent to the JVM.

Comment: The LVT is used only to aid debugging (that is you can see which variables are valid now in your Variables tab in debugger). It's completely unnecessary for code execution and can be switched off via `javac -g:none`.

Comment: @TagirValeev - So, the LVT is not used by the JVM?.. It's not part of the metadata?

Comment: @TagirValeev - Then why does the JVM spec says that every stackframe has 3 components : 1. Operand stack. 2. Reference to class constants pool. 3 local variable table.?

Comment: Of course, stackframe contains local variables, but they are created solely by parsing method signature (for input arguments), using max_locals value (to preallocate the table) and executing the code (for example, new entry is created when `astore` instruction is encountered). LVT from the class file is not used for this purpose.

Comment: @TheLostMind Where exactly does the JVM Spec say that, and what exactly does it say? It doesn't sound right.

Comment: @EJP - Ya. The spec says only this : *The Java Virtual Machine uses local variables to pass parameters on method invocation. On class method invocation, any parameters are passed in consecutive local variables starting from local variable 0* . So, it does use it *for non-debugging* purposes as well?.

Comment: @EJP - And it starts with this : *Each frame (§2.6) contains an array of variables known as its local variables. The length of the local variable array of a frame is determined at compile-time and supplied in the binary representation of a class or interface along with the code for the method associated with the frame (§4.7.3).*

Comment: @TheLostMind So there is nothing there about 'reference to class constant pool'? Or LVTs? Contrary to your claim above? So you have no basis for your claims here?

Comment: @EJP - Referring oracle docs :  *An array of local variables*  --> Local variable table.  *Run-Time Constant Pool* --> class constant pool. So, my claims aren't baseless :)

Comment: @TheLostMind I asked you to specifically quote where it says that a stack frame contains a reference to the class constant pool and the LVT. You haven't done it. I'm only a compiler writer, but a stack frame doesn't need to contain anything more than the operand stack, local variable slots, the value of the previous base pointer, and the return address.

Comment: @EJP - I am a *novice* java application programmer with an interest in JVM internals. So you will have to excuse me for my ignorance. :)

Comment: @TheLostMind I'm not discussing your alleged ignorance. I'm discussing your claim above that 'the JVM spec says that every stackframe has 3 components : 1. Operand stack. 2. Reference to class constants pool. 3 local variable table.' **Where does it say that?**

Comment: @EJP - From [Oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-2.html)  -- *Frames are allocated from the Java Virtual Machine stack (§2.5.2) of the thread creating the frame. Each frame has its own array of local variables (§2.6.1), its own operand stack (§2.6.2), and a reference to the run-time constant pool (§2.5.5) of the class of the current method.* .

Answer (score 1):

> I am however not sure if this will also remove the variables from the stack like a function which goes out of scope does?

It doesn't.

> What happens here under the hood?

Nothing at runtime.

> Does this differ from a function going out of scope

Yes. When a function returns the stack is popped and all the variables defined inside the function cease to exist. Including the ones in inner scopes like you are asking about.

> or a .. while/for .. loop that ends?

This is just another case of an inner scope. Nothing happens at runtime.

If a stack slot gets reused, the prior value disappears of course, which can lead to GC of the object that had been referenced by it. However just going out of scope doesn't cause that, or indeed anything. It can't. There is no bytecode instruction for an inner `}`.

Comment: Down voter please explain yourself.. If you think this answer is wrong, please let us know why?

Comment: I'm not saying it's incorrect. But I think it's not a very good answer, because it provides no explanation or background.

Comment: @popovitsj That claim is simply false.

Comment: @EJP - But *Tagir* says that the JVM will not use the LVT (check comments to my answer). Now, I am not quite sure. Because your last paragraph states that LVT is being used by the JVM.. Please clarify :)

Answer (score -1):

In java objects don't have distructors or methods to delete them so you cannot make them release the memory.

There is no guarantee that an object will be reclaimed the moment it leaves its declaring scope and no valid references to it exist. In a language like java that manages the memory for you this code you gave will not make a difference for the memory used.

So in java you better avoid such constructs. It can lead to error and harder to understand code.