# Does it make sense to convert a List to Iterator from a memory point of view?

Tags: scala, memory, garbage-collection, jvm

If I have a `List[HugeObjects]` with numerous elements that I have to iterate only once and no operations are made on it (e.g. appending, prepending, etc), does it make sense that I convert that `List` into an `Iterator`, so when I iterate it the elements will get *removed* and more memory will be available (because GC will take care of them at some point)?

Comment: I'd love to know why the question got downvoted. This is a question about JVM GC behaviour, particularly with Scala, and I couldn't find any similar question that could provide me insights about how this is being managed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I expected the answer to be "No, the iterator keeps a reference to the list, so as long as you use the iterator nothing will be garbage-collected."

But after looking at the actual implementation (https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.12.2/src/library/scala/collection/LinearSeqLike.scala#L41), it turns out it doesn't: there is a comment which specifically mentions not "prevent[ing] original seq from garbage collection", and

```
List("a").iterator.getClass().getDeclaredFields()
```

confirms `these` is the only field and so there is no hidden reference.

But! You don't say what is the operation you want to do on the `List`, but if you can convert to iterator, then the `List` code also probably loses references to the beginning of the list, and the garbage collector can collect it: [When is a Java local variable eligible for GC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1363075/when-is-a-java-local-variable-eligible-for-gc). There *might* be some differences in code generated by Scala which would block this optimization, but I wouldn't expect so.

Comment: I actually mention that I do not perform any operation, just iterate over it. I assume GC would collect the List since it got transformed to Iterator, but would GC collect the consumed items even though I haven't consumed the whole Iterator?

Comment: "Just iterating" (do you mean `for` or `foreach`?) is also an operation. Sure, if the only reference to those items is from the list, they will be collected (once GC starts).

Comment: I'd do `foreach`. I thought by operation you meant modifications performed on the List. Thanks!